# Check if username is not in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I managed to get my user updating his profile but I went in a problem : when my user wants to change his username, I face two problems :

1. If my user wants to change to an existing username in database, it will update on the existing username (not the user's current)
2. When the requested username doesn't existe in database, it wont update because there is no existing username

Here is my code to get all of the other fields working but the username's one...

```
exports.update = function(req,res){

  req.checkBody('username', 'Email is required').notEmpty().isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('surname', 'Surname is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('codePostal', 'Code postal is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('phoneNumber', 'Téléphone is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('address', 'Address is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('town', 'Town is required').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  console.log(errors);
  if (errors) {
    res.status(400).send(errors);
    return;
  }

  var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10),
  hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send('Error updating account.');
      }

      user.username = req.body.username;
      user.password = hash;
      user.name = req.body.name;
      user.surname = req.body.surname;
      user.codePostal = req.body.codePostal;
      user.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
      user.address = req.body.address;
      user.town = req.body.town

      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send('Error updating account.');
          return;
        }
        res.status(200).send('Account updated.');
      });
    });
}
```

Followed by a

```
userRoute = require('./server/api/user/index');
app.post('/account/update', authorizeRequest, userRoute.update);

function authorizeRequest(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized. Please login.');
  }
}
```

I already tried nested requests, but it simply doesn't work ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

What is your database user unique key ? For example if you have email address it can be unique and in that way you won`t have problems like that.

You need to rethink you logic again and decide which field will be your unique fields, and rewrite everything according to that.

Comment: My username field is already unique, you can't create an account with the same username already!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the client you have (Android, iOS, Angular), keep a hidden field containing the existing `username` of the user and another one which has the same value but which he can edit. Name them differently.

On back-end, find on original and update with new.

```
  req.checkBody('username', 'Email is required').notEmpty().isEmail(); // original/current
  req.checkBody('newUsername', 'Email is required').notEmpty().isEmail(); //new
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('surname', 'Surname is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('codePostal', 'Code postal is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('phoneNumber', 'Téléphone is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('address', 'Address is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('town', 'Town is required').notEmpty();
```

and

```
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send('Error updating account.');
      }

      user.username = req.body.newUsername; //pass new
```